# Is there anyway to clear signal mask set in bash script

Tags: linux, shell, signals

I'm trying look for any way to clear the process signal mask set in one bash script. Here's the problem:

My bash script is invoked by one C++ binary program which blocks some signals via sigprocmask function, thus, my bash script becomes one child process of the C++ process and inherits its signal mask set. Then, the bash script cannot receive the blocked signals any more.

So, is there anyway to clear the signal mask set in bash script?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the GNU coreutils **8.31** installed, you could try to use the "env"  command with --default-signal[=sig] (maybe together with a wrapper script that traps and forwards the signals), see e.g. the [env man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/env.1.html) or [GNU core utils manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/env-invocation.html).